# My php code upload does not upload all the files just some

Tags: php, file-upload

**[The problem is local. I uploaded the code to my school's server and the code worked everytime.  Thanks for all the answers and time from you guys, they helped me clean the code and now it looks better.]**

My php code upload does not upload all the files but just some.
My settings page is set to 4 upload boxes. My `index.php` works fine and it does send all 4 `$_FILES` info to the `upload.php` but when `upload.php` get it, it only uploads 2 or 1 files or sometimes all 4 but not all the files all the time.

I already checked and my `foreach loop` works fine.

Here is my code:

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php
        $RawSettings= file_get_contents('settings.txt');
        $settings = explode('=', $RawSettings);

        for ($x=1;$x<="$settings[1]";$x++)
        {
            echo '<input type="file" name="image'.$x.'"> <br>';
            echo $x.'<br>';
        }

        ?>

            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*upload.php*

```
<?php

$x=1;
foreach($_FILES as $image) {

    $varname = $_FILES['image'.$x]['tmp_name'];
    $vartype = $_FILES['image'.$x]['type'];
    $type = explode('/', $vartype);

    if ($type[1] == 'jpeg' || $type[1] == 'png')
    {
        $name = uniqid('picture');
        move_uploaded_file($varname, 'uploads/' . $name . '.' . $type[1] );
    }

    echo $x . '<br>';
    echo $varname . '<br>';
    $x++;

}
```

Thank you in advance for at least reading my question. The files have debugging echoes just to see if the loops are working.

**edit2**
here is the output from `print_r($type)`

```
        1
C:\xampp\tmp\php253.tmp
Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => jpeg
    )
    2
C:\xampp\tmp\php264.tmp
Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => jpeg
    )
    3
C:\xampp\tmp\php275.tmp
Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => jpeg
    )
    4
C:\xampp\tmp\php276.tmp
Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => jpeg
    )
```

Comment: Could it be that the files that are not uploaded have another file-end  than PNG or JPEG?

Comment: I am using the defaul images from Windows, all are JPEG. Even if I select the same picture it does not upload all 4

Comment: `for ($x=1;$x<="$settings[1]";$x++)` This looks quite funkey, Im not really sure what you are doing there. Do you intend to loop through the `settings` array or all settings under index [1] in the array? Or are you really trying to iterrate from 1 to whatever "$settings[1]" would cast to?

Comment: the $settings[1] is the number on the text file to choose how many upload fields i am gonna put. At the moment of the code it is 4. the content of settings.txt is 'number_of_uploads=4'

Comment: But you turn it into a string by using the "" marks. Echo out. Even if $settings[1] is 4, it will be turned in to a string "4". Which I would think is not what you are after.

Comment: The code, including settings.txt, works perfectly fine for me. Uploads four files every single time, even four of the exact same file. Could that mean that this is a local issue?

Comment: Can you put an 'else echo "If is not working";' after if($type...){...}? And echo the "type" from $_FILES? And, don't use the "type" from $_FILES for security reasons, because it can be spoofed by the user.

Comment: I also think is a local issue with xampp but my laptop is the same. As i said everything looks fine :"/

Comment: Im sure it is local now, I added this to my code  
echo "It worked for file number:" . $x . "<br>";
and the it returned 4 lines with number 1,2,3,4 at the end. So it mean the loop work and the actions are processed by the server but still no all images are uploaded.

Comment: I alse added the else and it only trigers if the file is not jpeg or png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     foreach($_FILES as $image) {

$varname = $image['tmp_name'];
$vartype = $image['type'];
$type = explode('/', $vartype);

if ($type[1] == 'jpeg' || $type[1] == 'png') {
    $name = uniqid('picture');
    move_uploaded_file($varname, 'uploads/' . $name . '.' . $type[1] );
 }
 }
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the help, I cleanned the code as you did but it still does not upload all pictures.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the `$x` in the `foreach`, because the `$image` is already populated with `$_FILES["image".numer]`. If you want to check if the key starts with image you can use an `strpos($key, 'image') === 0`.

It is possible that you are sending files with another starting name than "image", and in this case the `$x` will increment, and if you send 4 non-image file, PHP will try to read the nonexistent `$_FILES["image5"]`
And here is a more secure way to check the filetype:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mimetype = $finfo->file($image['tmp_name']);
```

But this will only work in PHP >= 5.3.0.
And you should use $image['tmp_name'] instead of `$_FILES["image".$x]["tmp_name"]`.

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $image){
    if(strpos($key, 'image') !== 0) continue; //Check if "image" is at the beggining of the key
    $varname = $image['tmp_name']; //Get the temp name
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME); //Make an instance of the finfo class with mime mode
    $vartype = $finfo->file($image['tmp_name']);//Get mimetype of tmp_name
    $type = explode('/', $vartype); 

    if (substr($type[1], 0, 4) == 'jpeg' || substr($type[1], 0, 3) == 'png')
    {
    $name = uniqid('picture');
    move_uploaded_file($varname, 'uploads/' . $name . '.' . $type[1].'NOPHP');
    }

    //echo $varname . '<br>';


}
```

Plus, with `explode('=', $RawSettings)` you can only load one setting, and, as said by commenters, you should remove the doule quotes from `$x<="$settings[1]`".

Comment: Thanks for the help, i cleaned the code where I could. Work the same on my home loca xampp server. I uploaded the code to my school server and the code work perfeclty every time. So it is a problem with my local server. Thanks for your time I took notes on what you wrote it made my code much better.